# How to open AlertDialog from preference screen?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am developing Application in android
I want to show AlertDialog  if user check the checkboxpreference from preference screen.
so how i can do that..?

Comment: It would help significantly if you let us know what technology and platform you are using. Please always provide as much context as you practically can.

Comment: It has an Android tag...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open AlertDialog from preference screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457944/how-to-open-alertdialog-from-preference-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onSharedPreferenceChanged` in your `PreferenceActivity` class:

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    ...
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("MyCheckboxPreferenceKey")) {
            //Show your AlertDialog here!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this one ...

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

      public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
                final Preference preference) {

         if(preference.equals("MyCheckboxPreferenceKey")) {

             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

         builder.setMessage("Your Message");

         builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

             //action on dialog close
           }

         });

         builder.show();

      }


}
```

Comment: @Dharmendra Actually, this requires a return statement and will require the main part of the method below to be added to cover "unimplemented methods"

Comment: I had up-voted this along the way , but coming back to it .. I am having an issue where method onPreferenceTreeClick() is not getting called. I found this post for current solution that helped me get this logic working http://stackoverflow.com/a/12325780/2162226

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity{
 ...
//getting current context for builder
AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//setting some title text
build.setTitle("SomeTitle");
//setting radiobuttons list
build.setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"One", "Two"}, 0, new OnClickListener() {                               

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Some behavior here    
            }
        });
        build.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Might be empty
            }
        });
                    //creating dialog and showing
        AlertDialog dialog = build.create();
        dialog.show();
}
```

That's all.