# How to open AlertDialog from preference screen?

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

My activity is below

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public class locationserviceSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener,OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.locationservice);

    //    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(notificationSettings.this, R.xml.notification, true);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Preference changed " + newValue);
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Shared preference changed" + key);
    }

}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Location service settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Location service"
            android:key="locationService" android:defaultValue="true"
            android:summary="checked for start location service in background"></CheckBoxPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Minimum time seconds"
        android:key="time" android:dependency="locationService"
        android:summary="Miminum time in seocnds for update location"></EditTextPreference>
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Minimum distance meters"
        android:key="distance" android:dependency="locationService"
        android:summary="Miminum distance in meters for update location"></EditTextPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

both of these method are not printing anything when i chacked the checkPreference

Comment: Use `Log.d(tag, msg);` instead of `System.out.println(msg);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`onPreferenceStartFragment()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#onPreferenceStartFragment%28android.preference.PreferenceFragment,%20android.preference.Preference%29). It became a replacement for deprecated `onPreferenceTreeClick`().

Answer (score 1):

Register your listener (for example in onCreate()) like this:

```
    timePref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("time");
    distancePref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("distance");


    timePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    distancePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```