# How to open a Dialog from a text entry on a PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog

In my Android app I want to show a Dialog if the user selects on something that looks like plain text in a PreferenceScreen.  I have seen [How to open AlertDialog from preference screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456993/how-to-open-alertdialog-from-preference-screen), but that solution launches from a CheckBoxPreference.

In my case, I'd like to launch from something that looks like a TextView (or I suppose it could be a button), and it would then lead to an "About" dialog I already have.  Any suggestions how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/@boramaapps/dialog-inside-android-preferences-1c50f93d2e8c

Answer (score 20, accepted):

preferences.xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:key="dialog_preference" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Activity:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

dialogPreference = (Preference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("dialog_preference");
dialogPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // dialog code here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, myki.  What would the xml type be for this specific preference?  Currently, I only have CheckBoxPreferences and EditTextPreferences.